# file upload fails with "Maximum request length exceeded."

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a service that keeps failing with the above error. There are numerous posts and article's about the default size for  file being 4mb and to increase the size via the web.config file. In my case the file size is 3.2mb so wouldn't expect to get this error. If I Increase the limit via the **maxRequestLength** attribute and the **maxAllowedContentLength** then this error is overcome. However, I'm trying to understand why I mighty be getting this error in the first place given that the filesize is below the 4mb limit. The file is an xml file and I'm posting to my service via postman.

Comment: What is the encoding of the file on disk, and which encoding are you using when posting it?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen they are both set to utf-8

Comment: Large files (and 3.2mb is a large file IMO) probably should be uploaded in chunks rather than just pushing it all in one go.  At least then you can show progress bars etc.  It's not an onerous task to upload this way (there are many examples on the web).

Comment: @mjwills Yes, as per my question. If I increase the limit, it works, but my question is why does it fail when the file size is less than the default 4Mb. So I dont even have those values set in the web.config

Comment: Please include the values of your config settings in your question.

Comment: Please share the request headers being used by the POST.

Comment: Ok, think I've found why I need to specify those values in web.config @LasseV.Karlsen put me on the right track. When I look at the file I'm readying it in Ascii format and it's saved locally in that format. When I send the file, it's going as UTF-8. Ascii takes 1 byte per character, but UTF-8 can take 1-4 bytes depending on the character, so my 3.2MB file could end up being sent at a file size of 12.8MB totally blowing the 4MB default size

Comment: Only if you have a file full of accents or japanese characters or things like that. It **could** end up being 12MB in size, but I seriously doubt it does. You could easily test by just doing `byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);` and then checking `bytes.Length` to see how many bytes you actually send.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes, it's taken it to 5.2MB